# How to filter array based on the value stored?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to filter the arrays based on the string stored.

```
array:3 [
  0 => "TEST_TEST1_ABC_20180920000000.txt"
  1 => "TEST_TEST2_ABC_20180920000000.txt"
  2 => "TEST_TEST1_EFG_20180920000000.txt"
 ]
//String format -> type_uniqueCode_outletCode_datetime.txt
```

TEST1 and TEST2 is unique identification for each user. Each user may have multiple outlet with unique outlet code but might same with other user.

If select TEST1, expected result to be as below

```
array:2 [
  0 => "TEST_TEST1_ABC_20180920000000.txt"
  1 => "TEST_TEST1_EFG_20180920000000.txt"
 ]
```

How can i do this and is it possible to do condition checking to know whether each user's outlet is attached to right unique code or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to compare each element of the array with your test string e.g.

```
$array = [
  0 => "TEST_TEST1_ABC_20180920000000.txt",
  1 => "TEST_TEST2_ABC_20180920000000.txt",
  2 => "TEST_TEST1_EFG_20180920000000.txt"
];

$test = 'TEST1';
$newarr = array_filter($array, function ($v) use ($test) { return preg_match('/^[^_]+_' . preg_quote($test) . '_/', $v); });
print_r($newarr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => TEST_TEST1_ABC_20180920000000.txt
    [2] => TEST_TEST1_EFG_20180920000000.txt
)
```

I've used [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) so that the `type` part of the field can be of arbitrary length. You can also make the search case-insensitive by adding the `i` modifier to the regex i.e.:

```
$newarr = array_filter($array, function ($v) use ($test) { return preg_match('/^[^_]+_' . preg_quote($test) . '_/i', $v); });
```

Finally if you want the array to be indexed `0,1,...`, just use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
print_r(array_values($newarr))
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => TEST_TEST1_ABC_20180920000000.txt
    [1] => TEST_TEST1_EFG_20180920000000.txt
)
```